# Can a Xamarin app be updated by downloading an image, CSS, or .js files using WCF service?

Tags: xamarin

Suppose we write a Xamarin MVC application which is deployed to a device and runs connected to the web.

If we need to update the application by downloading some images, CSS, or .js files using WCF service, for example, is that possible?

Does iOS, Android, and Windows allow you to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not update the app bundle itself on either iOS or Android, and presumably UWP but I am not very familiar with that platform so not sure. For iOS and Android the app bundles are signed so they can not be modified or else the signature will no longer be valid. You can, however, download anything you want and store the downloaded files in the file system. Every app does have a file system it can access to read and write from. See this Xamarin doc:

Forms:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

You might also want to look into the PCLStorage plugin:

Xamarin Component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/pclstorage

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCLStorage/

Source: https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage

(I know I should paste relevant bits from links, but there is just too much to paste and would end up pasting the whole article. If above link is broken, just google "Xamarin working with files")

*Note: I work for MS/Xamarin*